# how to move from one polygon to another in file in python?

Tags: python, points, arcpy

There are 3 polygons in shp. file.

need to find min / max of coordinate for each.
I can do it only for 1 by next:

```
import arcpy # csv
from arcpy import env

print "Creating and defining variables."
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Desktop\data"
env.overwriteOutput = 1

theme = 'interestAreas.shp' 
# Look for .next()  in SearchCursor, need a loop
# the same when we read line by line
for i in theme:
    Curs = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(theme, 'SHAPE@').next()
    polygon = Curs[0]
    ext = polygon.extent
del Curs

# Find min X, Y and max X, Y for each polygon and write it to the file:
print 'xmin is: ', ext.XMin
print 'ymin is: ', ext.YMin
print 'xmax is: ', ext.XMax
print 'ymax is: ', ext.YMax
minX = ext.XMin
minY = ext.YMin
```

How to do it by using arcpy  and loop for or while?
Or how to move through ID (1,2,3) of polygons?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code was very close. You just need to move and retune your `for` loop to iterate on the cursor, not the shapefile. I also recommend using `with` on the cursor object so you don't need to manage it.

```
import arcpy # csv
from arcpy import env

print "Creating and defining variables."
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Desktop\data"
env.overwriteOutput = 1

theme = 'interestAreas.shp' 
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(theme, ['SHAPE@']) as Curs:
    for i in Curs: # iterate through the rows in the cursor object
        polygon = i[0]
        ext = polygon.extent

        # Find min X, Y and max X, Y for each polygon and write it to the file:
        print 'xmin is: ', ext.XMin
        print 'ymin is: ', ext.YMin
        print 'xmax is: ', ext.XMax
        print 'ymax is: ', ext.YMax
        minX = ext.XMin
        minY = ext.YMin
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very used to python, but logic is mostly the same in every language... you should probably do something like this (there might be some minor syntax errors):

```
polygons = arcpy.SearchCursor(theme, 'SHAPE@')
curPolygon = polygons.next()
while Curs:
    polygon = Curs[0]
    ext = polygon.extent

    # Find min X, Y and max X, Y for each polygon and write it to the file:
    print 'xmin is: ', ext.XMin
    print 'ymin is: ', ext.YMin
    print 'xmax is: ', ext.XMax
    print 'ymax is: ', ext.YMax
    minX = ext.XMin
    minY = ext.YMin

    # now look for next polygon description
    curPolygon = polygons.next()
```

[for further reading click here](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/64)